# Add the following numbers and find the answer?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Sum the $3$ numbers from the list

> $?+?+?=30$  Fill the boxes using $1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15$

You can also repeat the numbers

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to get $30$ using the numbers from that list because all those numbers are odd. We know that `odd + odd = even` (that's the sum of any two numbers from the list) and `even + odd = odd` (we add one more number from the list to the sum which is even). So, the sum is always going to be odd, but $30$ is even!

Answer (score 2):

It's actually impossible since all numbers are odd and $30$ is even.

Notice that every odd number can be represented as $2n+1$. Thus $$(2n+1)+(2k+1)+(2t+1)=2·(n+k+t+1)+1$$ which is odd and not even